# Four-Dimensional Action Principle for a free particle

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

Following Landau & Lifshitz "The Classical Theory of Fields" chapter 2, p. 27, according to the principle of least action, we have (for a free particle):

$$ \delta S = -mc  \delta \int^b_a ds = 0.$$

To set up the expression for $\delta S$, we note that $$ds = \sqrt{dx_i dx^i}$$ and therefore

$$ \delta S = -mc \int^b_a \frac{dx_i \delta dx^i}{ds} = -mc \int^b_a u_i d \delta x^i.$$

My problem is that I do not understand the second equality here. The expression for relativistic velocity we are familiar with is $u^i = dx^i/ds$, so it is not clear how we have removed the square root on the fraction.

Furthermore, again after the second equality, the differential $d$ and the variation $\delta$ seem to be interchanged. Is it true that the variation commutes with the differential (i.e. that $\delta dx^i \equiv d \delta x^i$) in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your last question, yes in general the variation commutes with the differential. So the relation you write $\delta(dx_{i}) = d(\delta x_{i})$ is correct.

To address your first question, I believe you've made a arithmetic error that gave you the $\sqrt{ds}$ in the denominator, it should in fact be just $ds$. We can show this is the case as
\begin{align}
\delta S &= -mc\delta\int_{a}^{b}ds \\
&= -mc\int_{a}^{b}\delta(\sqrt{dx_{i}dx^{i}})\\
&=-mc\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{2}\frac{d\delta x_{i}dx^{i}+dx_{i}d\delta  x^{i}}{\sqrt{dx_{i}dx^{i}}}\\
&=-mc\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{2}\frac{2dx_{i}\delta dx^{i}}{ds}\\
&=-mc\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx_{i}\delta dx^{i}}{ds}
\end{align}
Hope this helps!

Also, see the related post [First variation of the action in relativistic notation - Landau & Lifshitz "Classical theory of fields"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135337/first-variation-of-the-action-in-relativistic-notation-landau-lifshitz-clas?rq=1).

Comment: Absolutely correct. It turns out that the edition I have (4th, reprinted) actually has the square root as a missprint, but it is much clearer now after your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As to your second question (commutation of variation and differential):

Variation means adding a small deviation function $\eta^i(\lambda)$ to $x^i(\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is an arbitrary parameterization of the spacetime trajectory. Then
$$\tilde{x}^i(\lambda)= x^i(\lambda)+\eta^i(\lambda)\equiv x^i(\lambda)+\delta x^i(\lambda)$$
Similarly for the derivative of the parameterization
$$\frac{d\tilde{x}^i}{d\lambda}(\lambda)= \frac{dx^i}{d\lambda}(\lambda)+\frac{d\eta^i}{d\lambda}(\lambda)\equiv \frac{dx^i}{d\lambda}(\lambda)+\delta\frac{dx^i}{d\lambda}(\lambda)$$
Since by my definitions $\delta x^i = \eta^i$, we finally obtain
$$\frac{d(\delta x^i)}{d\lambda}(\lambda)\equiv \delta\frac{dx^i}{d\lambda}(\lambda)$$
or written more compactly
$$d(\delta x^i)\equiv \delta (dx^i)$$
You see, the said commutation is nothing but a consequence of the ordinary derivative being a linear operator, when applied to the sum $x^i+\eta^i$.